# What's the difference between installing SSL certificate through MMC or a browser?

Tags: certificates, windows, web-browser

I want to understand What will happen behind the scenes When installing a certificate via MMC and browsers on Windows OS.

While installing some certificates using Internet Explorer, I noticed that certificate has not been added to MMC. But certificate was working fine in IE.

If it try the same certificate with FireFox will not work.

Does every browser save internally certificates?
How precedence work with browser's certificates over MMC ones?

Comment: Do you mean enrolling a client certificate? iE will create it in the same keystore as the MMC, but there are less management function. Firefox works with its own store, so there is no MMC alternative.

Comment: this is more of a Windows internals question than a security question